# JSON response is in array but still throws an error "NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-services

**TypeScript File**

```
export class CompanyComponent  {
  apiService : APIService;
  data : any;
  private companyUrl = 'http://localhost:4000/api/company/';

  constructor(apiService : APIService) {
    this.apiService = apiService;
    this.getCompanies(this.companyUrl);
  }

  getCompanies(url: any){
    this.data = this.apiService.GET(url).map((response :Response)=>
    response.json()).subscribe((response)=>{
    this.data = response;
    console.log(this.data);
  })
}
```

**Response array**

```
[
   {"_id":"58f61a132d44240d085ca2fa","comapny_name":"Burslem 
  Spice","__v":1,"categories":["58f643382d44240d085ca2fb"]},<br>
  {"_id":"590487964a45c56c0fa2911a","comapny_name":"Tiger 
  Bite","categories":[]}
]
```

**HTML file**

```
<div class="media">
  <div class="media-left" >
    <li class="media" *ngFor = "let comp of data" >
      <label>{{comp}}</label>
    </li>   
  </div>  
</div>
```

The above response is still in array but I get this error:

> **ERROR** caused by: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables
>   such as Arrays.

[image: Object is array]

Comment: `company` and `comp` are different!

Comment: @PriyeshKumar updated the change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data : any;` says data can be anything, but *ngFor accepts only Iterables.
Change it to `array`
Because you are loading async, when first time dom is rendered, `data` will be undefined and so angular will complain.

```
 export class CompanyComponent  {
      apiService : APIService;
      data : Array; // or array
      private companyUrl = 'http://localhost:4000/api/company/';

constructor(apiService : APIService) {
        this.apiService = apiService;
        this.getCompanies(this.companyUrl);
        this.data = []
}

getCompanies(url: any){
        this.apiService.GET(url).map((response :Response)=>
        response.json()).subscribe((response)=>{
            this.data = response;
            console.log(this.data);
        })
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="media">
  <div class="media-left" >
      <li class="media" *ngFor = "let comp of data" >
          <label> {{comp.company_name}}</label>
      </li>   
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: **data : Array** is not mandatory it can be **data : Any**  . The tricky part is **this.data = []** i think.

Comment: yeah! but you should define it as some built in datatype to get benefits of editor's intellisense and  that's what typescript is build for

Comment: Hi. I am having a similar problem. I have this method: getDropDownValues() {
    // this is all for user permissions isSA has certain permissions and so on.
    this.CompanyNames.permission()
      .subscribe(permValues => {

        if (permValues[this.selectedPerm]) {
          this.dropDownList = permValues[this.selectedPerm];
        }
        
      });

  }

Comment: I have declared dropDownList as an array. DropDownList = []; However, when I use `<option *ngFor = "let c of dropDownList" [value]="c.$key">{{c.$value}}</option>` I get error ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Comment: In the above code, I didnt highlight the code part, so : `getDropDownValues() { // this is all for user permissions isSA has certain permissions and so on. this.CompanyNames.permission() .subscribe(permValues => { if (permValues[this.selectedPerm]) { this.dropDownList = permValues[this.selectedPerm]; } }); }`

Comment: and what I get when I console.log dropDownList is: `{isCA: "Company Admin", isCL: "Company Level One", isCT: "Company Team Member", isFH: "Internal Team Member"}`

Comment: I found a solution. I used Object.keys(this.dropDownList) and then I used that to iterate in the *ngFor. However, is there any other elegant solution I can use in the .ts file itself?

Comment: @user165242, can you post it as separate question, as to get more people to see it and give note better answer